# Missing appearance option from "Tools" menu in texture paint mode

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

[image]while tring to add the texture to my unwrapped model while follwing a tutorial I've realized I'm missing the apprearance option in texture mode . is there any other way to do it? 
I have the 2.78 version. thank you

Comment: Please add a screenshot so we can see what you mean here - are you meaning texture draw mode in the header (if you have pie menu enabled, press Z and choose 'texture') or do you mean something else?

Comment: See in the Options tab on the Toolshelf, maybe that's what are you searching for